# Simple TableView Question

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Is there any way to make it so that the user cannot swipe-to-delete items? I can't find this property anywhere!!

This is Objective-C xCode iOS

Thanks,
Christian Stewart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't implement the commit editing style method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Already figured it out. Just don't implement commit editing style.

Comment: And supposedly I can only accept my answer in two days... If someone else wants to copy my answer and post it I will give you reps by accepting it.